# How to alias object property as variable in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm repeating over an array of objects and I want my variable in the loop to refer to just one property of each object.

Simplified data example:

```
var data = [
  {
    'name': {
      'first': 'John',
      'last': 'Johnson'
    }
    'age': 45
  },
  {
    'name': {
      'first': 'Larry',
      'last': 'Wilson'
    }
    'age': 45
  }
]
```

I could do:

`<div ng-repeat="person in data">{{ person.name.first }}</div>`

But what I'd prefer to do is to just focus in on the only part of the object I'm using and do something like this:

`<div ng-repeat="person.name in data as name">{{ name.first }}</div>`

But that doesn't seem to be working -- is this possible currently?

Comment: I guess not, however you could use ng-init `<div ng-repeat="person in data" ng-init="name = person.name">{{ name.first }}</div>`

Comment: This question turned up miraculously in a not-very-well-worded Google search. It was exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can do this with `ng-init`:

```
<div ng-repeat="person in data" ng-init="name=person.name">{{ name.first }}</div>
```

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInit

Answer (score 1):

Beware of using the "ng-init" trick. This will bind the "name" variable to a "person" object instead of making an actual alias for the data[$index].name expression you may want.

```
// Init model.
    data['fooPerson'] = {name: {first:"foo"}, age:64}
    $timeout(function(){
      data['fooPerson'] = {name: {first: "bar"}, age:51}
    }, 1000);
// Result after ~1 second:
// {{ name.first }} --> still "foo";
```

Comment: So what do you recommend?

Comment: PS. Great tip :-)